# How to filter record based on a filter condition in array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to filter records in an array of documents based on a condition?

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff32c8b6cff64b8582a7c12"),
    "Transaction" : [ 
        {
            "StatusCode" : "1",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("300"),
            "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2021-01-01T10:27:41.746Z")
        }, 
        {
            "StatusCode" : "2",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("-750"),
            "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2021-01-02T10:27:41.746Z")
        }, 
        {
            "StatusCode" : "1",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("1500"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2021-01-03T10:27:41.746Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above sample data, the result should be grouped by "status-code" and fetch the last transaction amount and status code by date.

Query :

```
[{$unwind: {
  path: '$Transaction'
}}, {$sort: {
  "Transaction.CreatedDateTime":1
}}, {$group: {
  _id: { StatusCode : '$Transaction.StatusCode'},
  Paid: {
    $last: '$Transaction.Amount'
  }
}}, {$project: {
  _id :0,
 StatusCode : '$_id.StatusCode',
 Paid : '$Paid'
}}]
```

Query Result:

```
{
    "StatusCode" : "1",
    "Paid" : "1500"
}

{
    "StatusCode" : "2",
    "Paid" : "-750"
}
```

From this query result we need to compare "Paid" value of Status code "1" & "2". If the paid value of status code "2" is not equal to paid value status code "1" , keep status code "1" record alone  and ignore the record of status code "2".

Expected Result:

```
{
    "StatusCode" : "1",
    "Paid" : "1500"
}
```

Comment: The query does exactly what you asked for: "group by status code and get the last transaction amount by Date and status code"  (however `{$sort: {"Transaction.Date": 1}}` is missing). The second sentence "the amount value of the status code should be the same" I don't understand. To be the same as what? What is the "amount of the status code"?

Comment: The amount should match on both status codes [1 & 2]  otherwise ignore the status code =2 category record. eg:  Here the Amount value 1500  is not equal to  Amount value 750.

Comment: Still not clear. 1500 is not equal to value 750 which should be "records should be removed" according to your requirement, i.e. the query should return nothing in this case.

Comment: You have two elements with `StatusCode: 1` - which one compare with what? When you say *If the paid value of status code 2 is not equal to paid value status code 1, keep status code 1* then this is equal to simple  "ignore status code 2, take always value of status code 1" (because if equal then status 1 = status 2) I give up!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your condition at all but in general it would be like this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         Transaction: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$Transaction",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.Date", {$max: "$Transaction.Date"} ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         Transaction: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$Transaction",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.Amount", 1500 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Your question does not contain any query.

Comment: sorry Wernfried Domscheit , I have updated the Query